# Syncfusion.DocToPDFConverter.DocToPDFConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion.DocToPDFConverter.DocToPDFConverter class to convert a Word document (DOC or DOCX) to PDF.

There is the ability to generate a PDF document with embedded fonts (that was used in Word document)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncfusion Essential DocIO library supports embedded fonts in Docx to Docx conversion and this is support is not available in Word document to Pdf conversion.

However we internally logged feature request for support embedded fonts in Word to pdf conversion in the future.

Also, you can contact our support team at support@syncfusion.com to get a prompt assistance for further queries on this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with following code before converting method call:

```
DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();
//set PDF conformance level using DocToPDFConverterSettings class property.
converter.Settings.PdfConformanceLevel = PdfConformanceLevel.Pdf_A1B;
```

set PdfA1b standard to embed the fonts in Word to PDF conversion.